# C#: Deserialization of JSON results in null list?

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize to my custom `AccountList` class to deal with the nested JSON but the `Accounts` list is always null?

Method:

```
public T GetJsonForEndpoint<T>(string endpoint)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(endpoint);
    var queryResult = _client.Get(request);
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(queryResult.Content);

    return data;
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "id": 435453435,
            "forename": "John",
            "surname": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "id": 2321323234,
            "forename": "Jane",
            "surname": "Doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Class:

```
public class AccountList
{
    [JsonProperty("accounts")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Accounts { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have neither provided a setter nor initialized your list, the serializer is probably just ignoring it (it can't set it to something non-null, or add elements to it).

It is usually a better idea to have immutable collection references, so I'd recommend just initializing your list like this:

```cs
public class AccountList
{
    [JsonProperty("accounts")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Accounts { get; } = new();
}
```

I'd also recommend avoiding the custom `[JsonProperty("accounts")]` and instead configure the serializer to respect camelCasing in its configuration as per the documentation:

- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm

Comment: Aha!! In my case, the issue was that my list was marked as readonly without being initialized. Thank you!